# Set state from FutureBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I've been trying to set a property based on a response from a `FutureBuilder` but can't seem to get it working. How can I set `_activityLength` after the future resolves without setting during build?

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: _future,
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('Press button to start');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  } else {
                    final documents = snapshot.data.documents;

                    _activityLength = documents.length;

                    return Expanded(
                      child: ListView.separated(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          height: 0,
                        ),
                        itemCount: documents.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => _activityTile(
                          documents[index],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              }
            },
          )
```

The `FutureBuilde` is in a `Column` widget in the body of the `Scaffold` and the value that I need to set is in the `_itemsHeaderText` Something like this:

```
body:
   ...

                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            bottom:
                                BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 15.0,
                              right: 15.0,
                              top: 10.0,
                              bottom: 10.0),
                          child: _itemsHeaderText(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      _itemsBody(),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full demo code below 
You can use `_future.then((value)` in `initState()` and do job in `addPostFrameCallback` like `setState`
And after future resolves, you can get `value` of `_future`, you can do further processing if need 
In demo code, I get `value` `length` and display on screen 
You can see working demo, data length change from 0 to 9

code snippet

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _future = _getUsers();
    _future.then((value) {
      print("data length ${value.length}");
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        print("other job");
        setState(() {
          _dataLength = value.length;
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

working demo

[image]

output

```
I/flutter (18414): data length 9
I/flutter (18414): other job
```

full code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: CategoryTab(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryTab extends StatefulWidget {
  CategoryTab({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _CategoryTabState createState() => _CategoryTabState();
}

class _CategoryTabState extends State<CategoryTab> {
  Future<List<CategoryList>> _future;
  int _dataLength = 0;

  Future<List<CategoryList>> _getUsers() async {
    var data = await http
        .get("https://appiconmakers.com/demoMusicPlayer/API/getallcategories");

    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    List<CategoryList> cat = [];
    for (var u in jsonData) {
      CategoryList categoryList = CategoryList(
          u["category_id"],
          u["category_name"],
          u["parent_category_id"],
          u["category_status"],
          u["created_date"]);
      cat.add(categoryList);
    }

    return cat;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _future = _getUsers();
    _future.then((value) {
      print("data length ${value.length}");
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        print("other job");
        setState(() {
          _dataLength = value.length;
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Categories",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("data length $_dataLength"),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: _future,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.data == null) {
                    return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(),
                          title: Text(
                            "${snapshot.data[index].categoryName}",
                            // subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].categoryId
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryList {
  String categoryId;
  String categoryName;
  String parentCategoryId;
  String categoryStatus;
  String createdDate;

  CategoryList(this.categoryId, this.categoryName, this.parentCategoryId,
      this.categoryStatus, this.createdDate);
}
```

Comment: I need something similar. I make requests based on a dropdown change, but I'm sure I can use your example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few workarounds to your question.

1. You could hoist the futureBuilder up the widget tree, instead of setting state the state will be reset once ConnectionState.done.
2. You could place the future in a function that is called on init state, then the result of the future you set state on it.